# Windows 8.1 - doesn't allow me to boot into firmware settings

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi

I have Windows 8.1 which is booted for sure in UEFI mode because of some reasons

1. I'm booting with UEFI Gop and my inital windows resolutions is Full HD.
2. This image:

[image]

3. My BCD configuration:

[image]

Nevertheless when I boot into Advanced Boot - there is no option to enter UEFI settings. How can I fix this?

Note:

My MB is B75M-GL with latest BIOS and UEFI support. Secure-Boot is enabled and 'Ultra Fast' boot too (which boots my GPU at GOP mode).

Comment: Cant you access the UEFI menu by pressing f2 during POST?

Comment: Try hitting Esc before Windows start (you probably have only 1-2 second window so type fast). On some BIOSes that gives you menu with available options.

Comment: I don't want to do this - I want to have this Windows option. Otherwise I should click the button like a robot. My question is how to fix this.